# what is the %o in this python file?

Tags: python

Here below is the expression of python. It converts integer to binary.

```
>>>octtab = {'0':'000', '1':'001', '2':'010', '3':'011',
      '4':'100', '5':'101', '6':'110', '7':'111'}
>>>def bin1(d, width=0):
    "integer to binary (string)"
    s = "%o" % d
    b = ''
    for el in s:
        b += octtab[el]
    if width > 0:
        if len(s) > width:
            return b[:width]
        b = b.zfill(width)
    return b
```

I don't know the meaning of %o. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Note: this is bad code. Most of it could be replaced with `bin(d)`, and the truncation when the binary is too long will cause problems somewhere.

Comment: Maybe that's from a really old program, but it's easier to use `"{:0{}b}".format(d, width)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%o` is [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). You use `%o` for octal numbers (i.e base 8 numbers):

```
>>> print "%o" % 011
11
>>> print "%o" % 8
10 # Because 010 == 8
```

Comment: Or perhaps more instructively `print "%o" % 8` which prints `10`.